# Signed request vs HTTP digest auth for API authentication?

Tags: authentication, http, digital-signature, man-in-the-middle, integrity

By signed request I mean something like this (simplified example):

Client creates a sig in his request:
`$sig = hash('sha256', $api_key.$data);` which generates `7409ur0k0asidjko2j` for example. He then  sends this to his request: `example.com/api/7409ur0k0asidjko2j`

Now, the receiving server then performs the exact process to perform a match for the sig.

Which is generally more secure, a signed request like this or an HTTP digest auth for the purpose of authenticating requests to an API server? Note we assume SSL is not installed.

Comment: There is no difference between these two - both are transmitted within same request.

Comment: You really cannot use TLS?

Comment: @curiousguy Well we can but for this example we don't really need to encrypt the whole HTTP traffic just the credentials.

Comment: @IMB So it is OK if the authenticated request is modified by an attacker?

Comment: @curiousguy Well how can you do that since either methods require you know the API secret first right? And the API secret is not transmitted in plain sight even without SSL.

Comment: @IMB With either method the access key (secret authenticator) is not transmitted in clear text at any time, and is not vulnerable (given it has sufficient entropy). But with HTTP digest, **only the user-password pair integrity is protected, not the request itself** (unless you are thinking of a different type of HTTP digest, if so please give a reference).

Comment: @curiousguy Yes that is exactly what I mean but how can an attacker modify the request? He must first know the user-password pair before he can send a modified request right?

Comment: @IMB No. The attacker would just intercept a request from you, wait until you complete HTTP digest authentication, then send anything he wants on the TCP connection.

Comment: @curiousguy To clarify what you're saying is possible with MITM attack right and that is also possible with SSL MITM attack?

Comment: No. TLS (SSL is over!) is what you use to avoid MITM. But only if you use it correctly: **properly validate the server TLS certificate**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the signature covers the whole request, then integrity is guaranteed. **Request replay is still a potential threat (think: resource abuse).**

With HTTP digest authentication, the request could be modified in transit. **You are at the mercy of a MITM (Man In The Middle) attack.**

Anyway, you should really use TLS provides **transport level security**:

- guaranty of **confidentially of payload**, not just of password or authenticator (but *not* payload size! be careful if payload size can reveal useful information)
- guaranty of **integrity of payload** (but *no* guaranty WRT client IP address!)

Comment: Are there other means of protecting agaist request replay other than SSL?

Comment: @IMB Obviously, you _can_ try to build your own cryptographic engine yourself. **But this is not recommended.** Is there a specific reason you are trying to avoid TLS? Just fear that it would be too costly?

Comment: Purely scientific purposes, SSL is cheap anyway but this is just for kicks.

Comment: @IMB You could use a request-id to avoid replay. That would complicate the server code if requests can be reorder during transit: the server would have to keep track of recent request-id, and also have an expiration feature so that old request-id cannot be reused. If requests are dispatched to several independent servers (all shared data is read only), that would imply that frequently modified data must now be shared between servers.

Comment: You are right this is complicated and messy. And the log will probably be so big. SSL it is.

Comment: @IMB Another possible approach would be to make the protocol *interactive* and use of a *server nonce* for each client request. This would give away the main advantage of not using TLS: that every request is just a bunch of bytes, that **can be sent without direct network connection** as (insecure) email, (insecure) FTP upload, or (insecure) living air carrier with memory card on the leg.

Answer (score 2):

Signing of the request might be better, but you should implement it correctly. The hash(key || data) construction is vulnerable to hash length extension attack and should never be used. Here you have good explanation of this subject: [Hash Length Extension Attacks](https://blog.whitehatsec.com/hash-length-extension-attacks/). You should use HMAC for message authentication.

Signing of the request is better than HTTP digest auth, because it could also protect the integrity of data sent in the request.

Comment: +1 "You should use HMAC for message authentication." Indeed, **HMAC is the tool designed by cryptographer for exactly this purpose (message integrity)**.